# How can I condense my code down to fewer lines?

Tags: python

I am creating a chemistry simulator type program that uses 42 different reacting species to generate an output when 2 species are combined. Each species has a value e.g. lithium is 1, sodium is 2 and potassium is 3. I have a def() statement set up to set each of these values when called, shown below.

```
def choselithium():
   global firstchoice
   global secondchoice
   global ChoosingAgain

   if ChoosingAgain == 0:
       firstchoice = 1
       vp_start_gui_whatnow()

   if ChoosingAgain == 1:
       secondchoice = 1
       vp_start_gui_areyousure()
```

This obviously becomes very inefficient after using these 12 lines 42 times, to the point where these simple statements are taking up over 400 lines of code. Is there any way I could condense these down into fewer lines, either by using a class or some such similar object? In this case, vp_start_gui_whatnow() and vp_start_gui_areyousure() start up menus that display the choice that was just made, the text value of which is picked from a database using the sql statement below:

```
def getfirstchoice():
    global output
    sqlcommand2 = "SELECT ChoiceDesc FROM Choices WHERE Choice_ID = ?"
    result2 = c.execute(sqlcommand2, (firstchoice,))
    result2 = [x for y in result2 for x in y]
    output = result2[0]
    return output

def getsecondchoice():
    global output2
    sqlcommand3 = "SELECT ChoiceDesc FROM Choices WHERE Choice_ID = ?"
    result3 = c.execute(sqlcommand3, (secondchoice,))
    result3 = [x for y in result3 for x in y]
    output2 = result3[0]
    return output2
```

Comment: In general, use for example a dict with mapping of values to keys. But can you extend your example, so it's more clear how the thing will work?

Comment: Requests for suggestions on improving working code, as opposed to fixing broken code, are generally a better fit for [Code Review StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That said, why do you have `firstchoice`, `secondchoice`, etc. as separate variables? Ideally, each piece of data should live in exactly one place, so a single variable indicating which species is in use makes more sense.

Comment: ...and using global variables with values that change at runtime -- more than one or two at most -- is a very, very big code smell (as in, an indicator that a design should be refactored).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It looks like this is incomplete code though. Should note that for this to be appropriate for Code Review, it should be "full code" that can be run.